# List index out of range Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to automate writing an Excel sheet and by using openpyxl I could write formulas to the cell of columns upto "N" but as I am trying to do the same for Column "O" I am getting Index error.

I tried adding Columns by using Insert_cols but it is showing me "name 'insert_cols' is not defined" And I am not sure it will solve my problem.

```
for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(sheet.columns)[14]):
     b=row+1
     c=row+14
     print (cellObj,b,c)
     n = '=AVERAGE(J%d:J%d)' % (b, c)
     # print n # check that n gets assigned correct string value
     cellObj.value = n
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ab8bd56d638c> in <module>
----> 1 for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(sheet.columns)[14]):
      2          b=row+1
      3          c=row+14
      4          print (cellObj,b,c)
      5          n = '=AVERAGE(J%d:J%d)' % (b, c)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I expected it to write it to the column "O" but it is showing me index error.

---Update

```
wbsheet.active()
sheet['Z7'] = '= SUM(A1:A5)'
```

I passed a random value to the cell Z7 like the code above , after that the list(sheet.columns) is consedering columns till Z can you please explain what is happening here and if there is a way to declare the number of columns I'll need rather than using the hack.

Comment: `list(sheet.columns)[14]` is limiting the list to a single element, is that what you mean to do there?

Comment: Yes,I want to limit the list to a specific column

Comment: Use `sheet.iter_cols()` for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way you are defining your list:

```
list(sheet.columns)[14]
```

This will convert sheet.columns to a list, but [14] will only give you the list element at index 14.

Would the following work for your implementation?

```
list(sheet.columns)
```

That way your for-loop get an actual list of columns which it can work with better.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I printed list(sheet.columns ) turns out list(sheet.columns) is only upto the column N Maybe that is why when I try to Access Column O I am getting the Error How Can I expand the list I tried to use Insert Columns but it is not working Please Help

Comment: I wrote a random number in the column z using
 sheet=wb.active 
sheet['Z7'] = '= SUM(A1:A5)'
now list(sheet.columns) is up to the column z although my program is working right now can you please educate me why this happens?

Comment: sure, please update the code with your new code and will take a look and try to help

Comment: I have updated the method/hack I used please take a look.@mbenhalima